# Coding PHP like asp.net - Is it possible?

Tags: php, asp.net, ide

While I know PHP extremely well, I was wondering if there is any frameworks / GUI's out there that allow you to develop PHP in the manor that you can develop ASP.net sites?  Most important features would be the separation of behind the scene's coding from the actual web view itself. This means each page has it's own class generated behind the scenes and can auto detect when certain buttons are clicked. It would be ideal for all this to be handled by the framework so I don't have to do it all.

Things like textbox1.text would be amazing, but I have no expectations of that.  Getting from the $_POST is ok.

Other key features I'd like is the ability to create classes with namespaces and #regions so i can easily access / see only what I want at a specific time.  A Data Access Layer object like .net would also be amazing so my SQL could stay clear and in an object form.

Again I am being very optimistic in asking if anyone knows of a setup like this, but figure it's worth asking as I have to develop a rather large PHP project and development time decreases 10 fold due to the usability of even Netbeans compared to ASP.net / Visual Studio.

I appreciate any input

Comment: just switch to ASP.NET. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: negative in a client driven atmosphere you don't always get the option to just switch.  Unfortunately there are many times I am forced to code in languages that are far from ideal, Object-C for iPhone apps being one.  This is a situation where the client is a state college who's only web service is unix based and only wants PHP development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest PHP framework I have seen is [Prado](http://www.pradosoft.com/).

> PRADO is a component-based and event-driven framework for rapid Web programming in PHP 5. PRADO reconceptualizes Web application development in terms of components, events and properties instead of procedures, URLs and query parameters.

I haven't looked at it in years though and the [old site](http://www.xisc.com/) says they have a new framework, but I'm not sure if it uses the same style.

Comment: That appears to be exactly what I am looking for but will research the new version along with the MVC's Deceze suggested.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a PHP framework with an MVC architecture. There are [a lot of those](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_frameworks#PHP) out there, so take your pick. It won't work exactly like .NET since it's a different technology, but you should definitely use a properly structured framework for any serious project.

Comment: I don't actually use MVC yet for ASP.net as I like the flexibility of ASP.net forms, but I guess even having the basics of the model view controller being separated is a huge step up from basic PHP.  Have any suggestions of good ones to look into using?

Comment: @Anthony Personally I'm pretty happy with [Cake](http://cakephp.org/), but I'd also recommend [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/). [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) and [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) have a lot of fans as well.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into all of them, including the PRADO and see which fits my needs best.  I appreciate the help